# After upgrading to 20.04.1LTS Text Editor is typing in gibberish

Tags: upgrade

After upgrading to 20.04.1LTS whatever I type in Text Editor comes out in symbols, not in letters.

Comment: Which text editor do you use? please provide more details and include a screen shot if you can.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually a post-upgrade, font-related issue. If you change the text editor to use something else, such as “Ubuntu Regular” or “Ubuntu Mono”, you should see correct characters.

Comment: sussed that one
had to choose a font for TextEditor (Ubuntu software)